# Injecting SignalR into a Core WorkerService

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-core-service-worker

I am trying to inject `SignalR` into a `WorkerService` project, and then simulate server-side notifications.

Further down in my `Worker.cs` file, I'm getting some null references - which tells me I'm not properly initially my Hub object.

I first created a `NotificationHub solution` with a project of the same name.

Here's `Notifications.cs` - which works fine.

```js
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotificationHub.Hubs
{
    public interface IHubClient
    {
        Task MessageReceived(string user, string message);
        Task MessageReceived(string message);
    }

    public class Notifications: Hub<IHubClient>
    {
        [HubMethodName("SendMessageToClient")]
        public async Task SendMessage(string username, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.MessageReceived(username, "from Notification Hub:" + message);
        }
        
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
            _ = SendMessage("From Server", "Hub reconnected on server.");
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write("Hub just disconnected on server.");
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

The `NotificationHub` runs in IIS on my local machine, which let's me call the Notification Hub from my `TypeScript` client.

i.e. I just added a simple `HTML button` to trigger a message from the client. My function fires:

```
   this.hubConnection.send('SendMessageToClient', 'client', `Message from client side. ${today}`)
                    .then(() => console.log('Message sent from client.'));
```

[image]

**Core WorkerService: My problem is here**

I then added a NotificationWorkService, in which I am trying to inject SignalR. The goal is to eventually have this service running on a Windows server which regularly checks for notifications, and delivers them to the browser.

In my WorkerService project, here's `Program.cs`

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace HarmonyNotificationWorkerService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
}
```

and here is `Worker.cs` -

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NotificationHub.Hubs;

namespace HarmonyNotificationWorkerService
{
    public interface IHubClient
    {
        Task MessageReceived(string user, string message);
        Task MessageReceived(string message);
    }

    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private IHubContext<Notifications> _hubContext;
        private readonly Hub<IHubClient> _hubNotif;
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
       
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection("/hub"))
            {
                IHubProxy hubproxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("https://localhost:44311/hub");

                await hubproxy.Invoke("SendMessage", "test");
            }
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
              
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task CheckForNotifications()
        {                      
            await _hubNotif.Clients.All.MessageReceived("from work server", "Dude, you've got mail!");
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Problem is that `_hubContext` and `_hubNotif` objects are always null, so I can't test either one. I'm def not initially them correctly, but I'm unsure of how to do that. C# is also showing me a warning about this null reference.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Data cannot be sent because the connection is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data.`

**UPDATE - INSTALL SIGNALR CLIENT PACKAGE**

I added `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;` to `Worker.cs`, and set a        `private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;` at the top of the `Worker` class.

Then I modified the following method to check the conn state, then send message:

```js
 private async Task CheckForNotifications()
        {
            if (_hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
            }            
            _ = _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessageToClient", "from service worker", "You've got mail!");
        }
```

It all seems to be working successfully.

The thread does exited with `code 0` at times, but I believe it's normal in this case since I'm running on a `Task.Delay(5000);`

Comment: The error message is indicating exactly what to do. 

`Call start before sending any data.`


   ie  `await hubConnection.Start(); `

Comment: Don't mix ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR. They are incompatible with each other.

Your worker should be using the HubConnectionBuilder to get a connection and send messages with it. https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#connect-to-a-hub

Comment: @Nkosi - there is no `Start()` method on my hub object. It's probably because I should have been using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` in my service, similar to how I use `'@microsoft/signalr'` in TypeScript for my Angular browser application.

Comment: @Brennan - yes, I read that somewhere, but I took the wrong approach. Now with the client package I am able to make a hub connection, and send two messages from my service to the hub - and then my browser client is able to handle the `messageReceived` event. However, my service is crashing out after a few seconds with an error. First you can see my `_logger` running fine, then the `thread has exited with code 0` ==> `NotificationWorkerService.Worker: Information: Worker running at: 06/26/2020 11:08:32 -04:00
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

Comment: @Brennan - I added an update to the end of my post. It runs for a few seconds then crashes. I've included the output message. Perhaps a new post is needed to solve the rest of my issues. Thank you.

Comment: I can only guess since your code isn't complete, but you're probably calling CheckForNotifications multiple times and since you included StartAsync in there it will try to start again and throw.

Comment: @Brennan - I figured it out. I had added some test code in Program.cs under `IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder` which was causing an exception. I'm sorry about that. It all seems to be working now. I'm also checking the state `if (_hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)`, which makes is cleaner. Can you add you comment as the answer ? I'm happy to choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR. They are incompatible with each other. Your server is using ASP.NET Core SignalR so your worker should create a `HubConnection` by using the `HubConnectionBuilder`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#connect-to-a-hub.

Comment: My WorkerService is now using the `HubConnection` class from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;`